# PostGIS update trigger

Tags: triggers, postgis

I have **table_1** having column  *point_id* and *geometry* (Point) ,
**table_2** has got columns: *area_id*, *geometry* ( Polygon) and a **table_3** which contains list of all the *point_id* from the **table_1**  and *area_id* from **table_2** , if    point   within the polygon.

I am trying to update **table_3** every time new polygon is added to **table_2**, so the *point_id* and *area_id* are populated  for every point from **table_1** which is within new polygon from **table_2**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locations_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
DECLARE
BEGIN 
  insert into table_3 (point_id,area_id)
    select
        table_1.point_id , new.table_2.area_id
    from
        table_1  
    join table_2  
on
    ST_WITHIN(table_1.geometry ,    new.table_2.geometry) ;
   RETURN new;
END;$func$
language plpgsql;



CREATE TRIGGER locations_update_tr AFTER INSERT ON table_2
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE locations_update();
```

What updates to the code above  needed to avoid unique constraint error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
DETAIL: Key (point_id, area_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the two tables, but the join condition is only considering the 1st table so it ends up being a cross-join.

In fact, you don't need to join at all since all the required information is in the `NEW` object.

```sql
SELECT
   table_1.point_id, NEW.table_2.area_id
FROM
    table_1  
WHERE
   ST_WITHIN(table_1.geometry, NEW.table_2.geometry) ;
```

PS: and of course you have another trigger to remove entry from table 3 when one is deleted in table 1 or 2.